# ng-zoro nz-calendar disable click on cells

Tags: angular

zoro ui. I have nz-calendar and want to disable clicks on cells.

```
  <nz-calendar
    [(ngModel)]="date"
    [(nzMode)]="mode"
  >
    <div *nzDateCell="let date" class="date-cell">
      <ng-container *ngIf="getCellWithData(date);let cell">
       {{fillCellWithData(cell)}}
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </nz-calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<nz-calendar
    [(ngModel)]="date"
    [(nzMode)]="mode"
    [nzDisabledDate]="disabledDate"
  >
    <div *nzDateCell="let date" class="date-cell">
      <ng-container *ngIf="getCellWithData(date);let cell">
       {{fillCellWithData(cell)}}
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </nz-calendar>
```

```
disabledDate = (current: Date): boolean =>true; // put your logic here
```